# In Kubernetes, how do I implement session affinity using an Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to implement a sticky-session Ingress controller. Cookies or IP hashing would both be fine; I'm happy as long as the same client is *generally* routed to the same pod.

What I'm stuck on: it seems like the Kubernetes service model means my connections are going to be proxied randomly no matter what. I can configure my Ingress controller with session affinity, but as soon as the the connection gets past the that and hits a service, `kube-proxy` is just going to route me randomly. There's the `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` flag on services, but that doesn't help me -- the Client IP will always be the internal IP of the Ingress pod.

Am I missing something? Is this possible given Kubernetes' current architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ingress controller can completely bypass kube-proxy. The haproxy controller for example, [does this and goes straight to endpoints](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/service-loadbalancer/service_loadbalancer.go#L155). However it [doesn't use the Ingress in the typical sense](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/pull/223).

You could [do the same with the nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/Ingress/controllers/README.md), all you need to lookup endpoints and insert them instead of the DNS name it currently uses (i.e swap [this line](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/Ingress/controllers/nginx-alpha/controller.go#L52) for a pointer to an upstream that contains the endpoints).

Comment: I have the same issue - but the links in your answer are currently broken, any chance you could update these?

I use a service of type LoadBalancer with a loadBalancerIP and sessionAffinity: "ClientIP" but it seems that the users are not hitting the same pod.

Comment: I found [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/aman-tiwari/728cccf97b3202617ec4589a4f89fd77) very useful in setting up a load balanced app with Cookie based stickyness and haproxy. Basically it comes down to set the not-so-well documented `serviceloadbalancer/lb.cookie-sticky-session` on the service you like to balance, and let haproxy do the magic in front.

Comment: Broken link for the github URL

Answer (score 1):

I evaluated the haproxy controller but could not get it running reliably with session affinity. After some research I discovered [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx) which since version 0.61 also includes the *nginx-sticky-module-ng* module and is now running reliably since a couple of days in our test environment. I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tillkuhn/c2dba43d60d3e7a2462928812ca9e4bf) that sets up the required Kubernetes pieces since some important configuration is a bit hard to locate in the existing documentation. Good luck!